# if the index are not integer how we can insert in hash table in c++

Tags: c++, hash

If I have 4 data like 1,2,3,4 and the hash table size is 5 then we can insert it according to the index, and search the item based on the index with the hash function like below.

```
h(x)= x%5
```

Insert function:

```
void insert(int key,int data) {
   struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
   item->data = data;  
   item->key = key;     

   //get the hash 
   int hashIndex = hashCode(key);

   //move in array until an empty or deleted cell
   while(hashArray[hashIndex] != NULL && hashArray[hashIndex]->key != -1) {
      //go to next cell
      ++hashIndex;

      //wrap around the table
      hashIndex %= SIZE;
   }

   hashArray[hashIndex] = item;        
}
```

Lets say if the data we have are string values, how can we implement hashing with it?

Comment: By the way, why are you using not `new` but `malloc()` in C++?

Comment: It seems like you just need to provide a `hashCode` overload for your `key` type.

Comment: Please, don't do `struct DataItem *item = (struct DataItem*) malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));` in C++.  If you must manually allocate something use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Check [`std::hash`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash)

Comment: You also handle hash collisions in a way that will exhaust the table and fill it up. And more importantly, you don't have any out-of-bounds checking of your (I suppose) array!

Comment: You hash the string. I'm sure there are plenty of resources out there that can teach you how to do so, all you have to do is to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

As the name echoes, a hash table requires a hash function, i.e. a function that associates an integer in [0,4] to your key, whatever its type. The hash function should be such that collisions are minimized, so it shouldn't cluster the values.

For character strings, you often use a CRC-like conversion to get an integer.